# Case выполняется только один раз

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Пытаюсь в джаву. Пытаюсь сделать простой консольный каталог, делаю пункты главного меню, которые можно выбрать, если ввести цифры `1`, `2`, `3`. При выборе пункта содержимое текстового файла выводится на экран. Возникла такая проблема: можно выбрать пункт только один раз, после чего нет никакой реакции на последующий ввод цифр. Данные с консоли считываю с помощью `BufferedReader`. Сам выбор пунктов делаю с помощью `switch-case` (с `if-else` результат тот же). Надеюсю, что нормально описал суть проблемы.

**Main.java**

```
package filework;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,"Cp1251"));
        
        readFile r = new readFile();
        Menu.menu(args);
       
    }
}
```

**Menu.java**

```
    package filework;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Menu {
    
    public static void menu(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,"Cp1251"));
        
        readFile r = new readFile();   
        
        String menu_text = "========== Catalog ==========="
            + System.lineSeparator() + ""
            + System.lineSeparator() + "1: About catalog"
            + System.lineSeparator() + "2: Tile-entity"
            + System.lineSeparator() + "3: Tile-entity list"
            + System.lineSeparator() + "'exit'"
            + System.lineSeparator() + "===============================================";
                
        System.out.println(menu_text);
        String data;
        String path;
        data=in.readLine();
        
        switch (data) {
           case  ("1"):
                path = "D:\\Study\\java\\Test\\Assets\\About Catalog.txt";
                r.printFile(path);
               break;
               
           case ("2"):
                path = "D:\\Study\\java\\Test\\Assets\\About Block-Tileentity.txt";
               r.printFile(path);
               break;
               
           case ("3"):
                path = "D:\\Study\\java\\Test\\Assets\\About Block-Tileentity.txt";
               r.printFile(path);
           default:
               
       }
        
        while(!data.equals("exit"))
        {
            data=in.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**FileRader.java**

```
 package filework;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class readFile {
    private BufferedReader in;   
    /**
     * метод выводит содержимое файла на экран
     */
    public void printFile(String filepath){
        try {
            
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filepath),"utf-8"));
            System.out.println("============================");    
            
                String s = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(s);                
            
            System.out.println("============================");
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слишком сложно. Если у вас есть много классов, то это еще не означает, что ваш код превратился в ООП. Вы просто разбили процедурный код на множество классов. ООП проявляется в полиморфизме, а полиморфизм невозможен без наследования. Посему давайте немного упростим:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileReader {
    
    private final static String DOC_SEPARATOR = "============================";

    private final static String MENU_TEXT = "========== Catalog ==========="
            + System.lineSeparator() + ""
            + System.lineSeparator() + "1: About catalog"
            + System.lineSeparator() + "2: Tile-entity"
            + System.lineSeparator() + "3: Tile-entity list"
            + System.lineSeparator() + "'exit'"
            + System.lineSeparator() + "===============================================";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            break_point:while (true) {
                System.out.println(MENU_TEXT);
                switch (scanner.nextLine()) {
                    case ("1"):
                        printFile("D:\\Study\\java\\Test\\Assets\\About Catalog.txt");
                        break;
                    case ("2"):
                        printFile("D:\\Study\\java\\Test\\Assets\\About Block-Tileentity.txt");
                        break;
                    case ("3"):
                        printFile("D:\\Study\\java\\Test\\Assets\\About Block-Tileentity.txt");
                        break;
                    case ("exit"):
                        break break_point;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static void printFile(String filepath) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filepath), "utf-8"))) {
            System.out.println(DOC_SEPARATOR);
            in.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
            System.out.println(DOC_SEPARATOR);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Да, похожея, мне ещё действительно рано в ООП. Спасибо за ваш ответ, он мне помог

Comment: @Tom не за что, удачи в изучении

Answer (score 1):

Мсье сверху с 7,5 тысяч рейтинга и серебренным значком за джаву знает толк в извращениях. Такому кодстайлу придерживаться новичку крайне не советую, чистое ИМХО.
А теперь по пунктам, почему я, собственно, тут развонялся:

1. Неправильный порядок модификаторов. Согласно спецификации сначала `static` потом `final`. Как бы мелочь, но все-таки спецификации языков существуют неспроста.
2. В методе `printFile()` используется монструозных размеров синтаксическая конструкция для чтения файла. Хотя до этого в `main` автор использовал `Scanner`, который бы с этой задачей прекрасно бы справился.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filepath);
```

3. Goto. goto? goto. Хорошо, когда есть неисчисляемое количество вложенных циклов `break` с меткой необходим. Но не здесь же. Да и зачем? Вроде как exit подразумевает выход из программы.
4. `System.lineSeparator()` почему бы не заменить на `\n`?
5. `case "2"` и "3" идентичен.
6. Почему бы не вынести путь к файлам в константу? А как же DRY?

Дабы не быть голословным прикладываю свой говнокодец:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileReader {

    private static final String DOC_SEPARATOR = "============================";

    private static final String MENU_TEXT = "========== Catalog ===========\n\n"
            + "1: About catalog\n"
            + "2: Tile-entity\n"
            + "3: Tile-entity list\n"
            + "'exit'\n"
            + "===============================================\n";

    private static final String ROOT_DIR = "D:\\Study\\java\\Test\\Assets\\";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(MENU_TEXT);
                System.out.print(">>> ");
                String input = scanner.nextLine();
                switch (input) {
                    case "1":
                        printFile(ROOT_DIR + "About Catalog.txt");
                        break;
                    case "2":
                    case "3":
                        printFile(ROOT_DIR + "About Block-Tileentity.txt");
                        break;
                    case "exit":
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Unknown command");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printFile(String filepath) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filepath))) {
            System.out.println(DOC_SEPARATOR);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            System.out.println(DOC_SEPARATOR);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S**
К автору вопроса претензий у меня нет и быть не может. Все вопросы адресованы исключительно к системному архитектору предыдущего ответа. Автору желаю успехов в обучении сию ремеслу и высокооплачиваемого трудоустройства!

Comment: Если убрать переход на личности и разговорно-ругательные выражения, то получится вполне себе ответ.

Comment: @kami, согласен, кое-где можно было бы и потактичнее с моей стороны. Но это собо не меняет качества того ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Так у вас же switch вне цикла. Вы сначала 1 раз читаете строку ввода, выполняете switch-case, а затем в этих строках:

```
 while(!data.equals("exit"))
    {
        data=in.readLine();
    }
```

просто в цикле читаете данные с клавиатуры, не вызывая case.
Как вариант  - можно вынести switch-case в отдельный метод, и вызывать его в цикле чтения данных, примерно так:

```
while(!data.equals("exit"))
{
       data=in.readLine();
       proccessInput(data);
}
```

Вообще - код конечно требует серьезного рефакторинга, но это сильно выходит за рамки обсуждаемого вопроса:)